# How can encrypted Apple DMGs be so fast to open?

Tags: dmg, tar, gpg

On remote drive I have an encrypted .dmg and the same files in a gpg encrypted tar file. 
The DMG opens within seconds, but to access the tar file, I first need to decrypt it, in this 10 minutes, and then expand it, another 10 minutes.

How can the Apple DMG be so fast? or where I read more about how it works?

Comment: Without looking into the details I would assume that decrypting a DMG happens on the fly when you access the content, but decrypting a GPG tar requires the whole file to be decrypted before its content can be accessed.

Comment: would correct then the Linux equivalents are encrypting each file individually and not using tar, or having an encrypted partition.